# TFS 2013 build with xUnit and MsTest both

Tags: build-process, mstest, xunit

Does TFS 2013 using (tfvcTemplate.12.xaml) support multiple test runners? We have two unit test projects in our solution (MsTests and XUnit). I would like the build to run xUnit tests as well as MsTests.

**Projects:**

- MySolution.UnitTests (mstests)
- MySolution.UnitTests.xUnit (xunit tests)

I have VS2013 installed on the build server.

Looks like MsTests are run fine, but not xUnit. The results show only MsTests and no xUnit tests. 
[image]

**How would I specify xUnit to be also executed?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the xUnit runner Nuget package to your xUnit project.  I think this is the right package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/2.1.0